# want to add a delete image to this code, using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
   var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

   // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
   for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

   // Only process image files.
   if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
       continue;
 }


var reader = new FileReader();

// Closure to capture the file information.
reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
return function(e) {

    // Render thumbnail.
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');

    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
};
})(f);

  // Read in the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
 }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: <img src="http://wecision.com/enterprise/images/icons/closeIcon.png" style="position: absolute; top: 4px; right: 5px"/>    This image need to be added to each file that appears as thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like::

```
function addImage(parentEle) {
 var img = document.createElement("IMG");
 img.setAttribute('src',"Your_image_src_here");
 img.style.position = 'absolute';
 img.style.top = '4px'; 
 img.style.right = '5px'; 
 parentEle.appendChild(img);
}
```

and

```
span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
//call the function
addImage(span);
document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
```

Comment: This code gives the delete image on the right top of the screen but it is not being reflected on the images's right top. Moreover, it has to appear on every image that appears in the thumbnail.

Comment: I need the DELETE image on the image of each thumbnail so that I can delete the image by clicking on that button.